# Can Evaluate be used to set the value of a global variable without calling a macro or function?

Tags: vba, vb.net, evaluate

My requirement is to use .Evaluate() from VB.net to set a variable in an Excel VBA add-in. I have access to the sheet in VB.Net. Therefore I can easily execute iSheet.Evaluate("MyMacro(12)"). The add-in's MyMacro() is certainly capable of setting the value of a global variable. However, we are looking for a way to avoid having to modify the add-in to get the global variable set.

I was hoping that I could call (from VB.net) something like iSheet.Evaluate("myVar = 12"). Is there a way to use an existing VBA function or Evaluate syntax to set a variable to a value given the name and value in a string?

Comment: This honestly seems like an XY problem and a code smell.

Comment: `Evaluate` is for calling methods/properties - it can't be used to execute random snips of VBA.